# Can I transfer items between two of my RuneScape accounts?

Tags: runescape

I have a non-member account with a purchased dragon plate body, but then I stopped playing.  I have now made a different account and I am paying for it.  I remembered my old account (the one with the dragon plate body) but he is a non-member, so is there a way to trade my stuff from a non-member to a member?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason why you can't have a friend login in your old account and meet him somewhere where non-members have acesss to and trade the item there. As long as, of course, the item in question is not a members only item, then your non-member character can't do anything with it. This was of course like 10 years ago that I played RuneScape so a lot may have changed.

Comment: This should still work.

Comment: This doesn't work due to trade limit. You need to transfer the current GE value (minus a bit) in gp or items to your other account to balance the trade.

Answer (score 5):

### No

You can't do this for 3 reasons:

1. Trading Limit (you can't trade expensive items for no return)
2. Trading between your accounts risks both being banned
3. You can't log in twice on the same computer

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to do this, especially with someone else logging in to your non-member account, doing so violates the [multiple log in rule](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Multiple_logging-in) of the game:

> You are free to create more than one account, but if you do, you must
>   not log into more than one at any time, and **the accounts must not
>   interact with each other in any way**.

Trading the item between your accounts risks having both accounts banned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just get 2 computers and separately login into 2 account and transfer. If you have any trade limit, do quests, it may help you get rid of the limit (That's how I got rid of mine).